# How to create a ClassTag<Dataset<Row>> in Java

Tags: scala, apache-spark, generics, apache-spark-sql

I am writing a spark-sql query that needs to broadcast something.

Now I have some codes like this. The generic type parameter is wrong.

```
final Broadcast<Dataset<Row>> b = sparkSession.sparkContext().broadcast(
                sparkSession.sql("My SQL"),
                classTag(Dataset.class)
        );
```

The createTag method:

```
private static <T> ClassTag<T> classTag(final Class<T> clazz) {
        return scala.reflect.ClassManifestFactory.fromClass(clazz);
}
```

How can I make the code compiles?

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to cast it in a kind of ugly way:

```
classTag((Class<Dataset<Row>>) (Class<?>) Dataset.class)
```

Unfortunately, I don't know a better solution.